# PHP mySQL Warning trying to connect to database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying a secure login tutorial and have tried searching for my warning but it seems to be missing an actual message.

> PHP Warning:  mysqli::mysqli():  in
>   D:\wamp\www\includes\db_connect.php on line 3

Most people with an error on this function have got their username and password wrong but I have triple-checked these and they are fine.

The offending code is:

```
<?php
include_once 'psl-config.php'
$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE);
?>
```

I can connect to my database fine in a different project, and I don't see a difference between the code.

I am running PHP 5.5.12 and mySQL 5.6.17

Comment: So this is a warning. Your database connection created successfully or not? Try `$mysqli->connect_error` to check what is going on

Comment: Also check that  constants `HOST` `USER` etc are defined and exist, do a `var_dump()` of them after config `include`

Comment: thanks guys, that was what I needed to diagnose the problem I used var_dump($mysqli->connect_error)

Comment: *blushes* I triple checked the wrong password. At least I learned valuable php functions along the way!

Answer (score 0):

$mysqli->connect_error gives

```
'Accès refusé pour l'utilisateur: 'Users'@'@localhost' (mot de passe: OUI)'
```

Which means WRONG PASSWORD.

I had the wrong password.